# Does this limit exist? if so what is it?

Tags: limits

Given the set
$A_n =\{(i,j)∈ Z^2:(i,j)=1, 0≤i,j≤n\}$ 
I am having problems proving that the limit
$\lim_{N\to \infty}$  $|A_n|\over N$
exist and to calculate it,
any tips?

Comment: Assuming you mean $n$ and $N$ to be the same, the limit doesn't exist. If you divide by $n^2$ instead of by $n$, the limit is $6/\pi^2$. The proof is not hard --- if you've done an intro course in Number Theory. You'll find a proof in many Number Theory texts.

Comment: See also the discussion at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425954/sum-of-greatest-common-divisors

Comment: Is some question considered "duplicate" if its answer can be obtained from the results of *another* one easily? Then much more questions here are duplicates...

Comment: @njg, I wrote *possible* duplicate because I'm guessing that OP meant to divide by $n^2$ instead of $n$. If my guess is right, it's a duplicate. If my guess is wrong, well, OP can let us know.

Answer (score -1):

For every $k$ and $m$ we have: $(2^k, 2m+1)=1$. Therefore $|A_{2^n}| \ge n 2^{n-1}$ and
$$\frac{|A_{2^n}|}{2^n} \ge \frac{n}{2},$$
i.e the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Why the downvote? I answered **before** "possible duplicate" comment.